# How to call a function once the back button is clicked in recact native

Tags: react-native, navigation

After i do `navigation.goBack();` to go back to a page i want to run a function, how can i do that?,
NOTE: if i am redirecting from pageA to pageB, i want to run the function once i get to pageB, and i also want to solve for going back with the physical back button

This is what i have tried:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={() => {
     navigation.goBack();
     }}>
     <Ionicons
     name="chevron-back-outline"
     size={24}
     color="#000"
     style={{}}
   />
 </TouchableOpacity>
//this is pageA


  useEffect(()=>{
    getUserInfo()
  })
//on pageB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, for this purpose you can use the `useFocusEffect` this hook runs once every time you focus again on a view allowing yo to execute some code just after the goBack function takes effect.

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const PageB = () => {
  // ... other code for pageB
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      getUserInfo();
      // Return a cleanup function if necessary
      return () => {
        // Cleanup code (if needed)
      };
    }, [])
  );
};
```

**Intercepting Backbutton event:**

With this purpose, you can simply use the `BackHandler` event listener:

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
  const backAction = () => {
    getUserInfo();
    return true;  // Prevent default behavior (optional)
  };

  const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
    'hardwareBackPress',
    backAction
  );

  return () => backHandler.remove();
}, []);
```

I Hope it works for you!